# text align center for tspan text block

Tags: d3.js

Below sample generate text block but current test is align left, how to align text by center?

```js
demo()
function demo() {
        var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                .attr('width','100')
                .attr('height','100')
                .attr('transform','translate(50,50)')
        
        var text = ["12","123456789","1234"]

        var fontsize = 40
        var txt = svg.append('text')
                .attr("text-anchor", 'start')
                .attr("dominant-baseline","middle")//text-before-edge
                .attr("font-size",fontsize)
                .attr('alignment-baseline','middle')

        var tspan = txt.selectAll('tspan')
                .data(text)
                .join('tspan')
                .attr('class','tspan')
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr('y',function(d,i) {
                        return i*fontsize
                })
                .text(d => d)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

*Update*

After apply @herrstrietzel's answer, I create below demo to show the usecase to put text box at specific position, currently it always at the center of svg, I wish it deployed at specific location (x,y).

```js
demo()

function demo() {
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 300)
            .attr('height', 200)
            .style('background','#ececec')

        add_grid(svg)

        var data = [
                {
                        text:["B", "BB", "BBB",'BBBB'],
                        x:50,
                        y:50
                },
                {

                        text:["AAAAA", "AAA", "A"],
                        x:150,
                        y:100
                }
                ]
        
        var fontsize = 20
        var txt = svg.selectAll('.box')
                .data(data)
                .join('text')
                .attr("text-anchor", 'middle')
                .attr("x", '50%')
                .attr("y", '0%')
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("font-size", fontsize)
                .style('border','1px solid red')
                .attr('x',d => d.x)
                .attr('y',d => d.y)

  var tspan = txt.selectAll('tspan')
    .data(d => d.text)
    .join('tspan')
    .attr('class', 'tspan')
    .attr("x", '50%')
    .attr('dy', function(d) {
      return fontsize * 1.2
    })
            .text(d => d)
            
        function add_grid(svg) {
                var w = +svg.attr('width')
                var step = 10
                var mygrid = function(d) {
                        return `M 0,${d} l ${w},0 M ${d},0 l 0,${w}`
                }

                var grid = []
                for(var i = 0; i < w; i+=step) {
                        grid.push(i);
                }

                svg.append('g')
                        .selectAll(null)
                        .data(grid).enter()
                        .append('path')
                        .attr('d',d => mygrid(d))
                        .attr('fill','none')
                        .attr('stroke','green')
                        .attr('stroke-width',.5)
        }       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is aligned left since your `text-anchor` value is "start" instead of "middle".

#### Working example

```js
demo()

function demo() {
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100')
    .attr('height', '100')
  //.attr('viewBox','0 0 100 100')
  var text = ["12", "123456789", "1234"]

  var fontsize = 20
  var txt = svg.append('text')
    .attr("text-anchor", 'middle')
    .attr("x", '50%')
    .attr("y", '0%')
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("font-size", fontsize)

  var tspan = txt.selectAll('tspan')
    .data(text)
    .join('tspan')
    .attr('class', 'tspan')
    .attr("x", '50%')
    .attr('dy', function(d) {
      return fontsize * 1.2
    })
    .text(d => d)
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[`dy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy) can actually be better suited to mimic line breaks.

**Worth mentioning:**

- there are no block-like elements in svg:
- the parent **svg won't automatically grow or shrink** according to it's content/child node dimensions ( so you need to calculate an appropriate height and with depending on your text length)
- `<text>` elements need a `x` value of "50%" or "viewBox width/2" to be centered

I strongly recommend to test the best `<text>` properties "statically" (e.g. in a codepen or a static html)

#### Second example:

You need to set the same `x` value for both `<text>` and `<tspan>` elements to **mimic a center aligned text block**.
Red circles illustrate the desired horizontal/vertical center points.

```js
demo();

function demo() {
  var svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .style("background", "#ececec");

  add_grid(svg);

  var data = [
    {
      text: ["B", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB"],
      x: 50,
      y: 50
    },
    {
      text: ["AAAAA", "AAA", "A"],
      x: 150,
      y: 100
    }
  ];

  var fontsize = 20;
  var txt = svg
    .selectAll(".box")
    .data(data)
    .join("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "text-bottom")
    .attr("font-size", fontsize)
    .attr("x", (d) => d.x)
    .attr("y", (d) =>{
      let textL = d.text.length;
      let yOffset =  d.y - (fontsize * 1.2 * textL/2);
      return (yOffset);
    });

  var tspan = txt
    .selectAll("tspan")
    .data((d) => d.text)
    .join("tspan")
    .attr("class", "tspan")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      let currentX = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("x");
      return currentX;
    })
    .attr("dy", function (d) {
      return fontsize * 1.2;
    })
    .text((d) => d);
  

  function add_grid(svg) {
    var w = +svg.attr("width");
    var step = 10;
    var mygrid = function (d) {
      return `M 0,${d} l ${w},0 M ${d},0 l 0,${w}`;
    };

    var grid = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < w; i += step) {
      grid.push(i);
    }

    svg
      .append("g")
      .selectAll(null)
      .data(grid)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", (d) => mygrid(d))
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "green")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="300" height="200" style="background: rgb(236, 236, 236);">
  <g>
    <path fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5" d="M0 0l300 0m-300 0l0 300m0-290l300 0m-290-10l0 300m-10-280l300 0m-280-20l0 300m-20-270l300 0m-270-30l0 300m-30-260l300 0m-260-40l0 300m-40-250l300 0m-250-50l0 300m-50-240l300 0m-240-60l0 300m-60-230l300 0m-230-70l0 300m-70-220l300 0m-220-80l0 300m-80-210l300 0m-210-90l0 300m-90-200l300 0m-200-100l0 300m-100-190l300 0m-190-110l0 300m-110-180l300 0m-180-120l0 300m-120-170l300 0m-170-130l0 300m-130-160l300 0m-160-140l0 300m-140-150l300 0m-150-150l0 300m-150-140l300 0m-140-160l0 300m-160-130l300 0m-130-170l0 300m-170-120l300 0m-120-180l0 300m-180-110l300 0m-110-190l0 300m-190-100l300 0m-100-200l0 300m-200-90l300 0m-90-210l0 300m-210-80l300 0m-80-220l0 300m-220-70l300 0m-70-230l0 300m-230-60l300 0m-60-240l0 300m-240-50l300 0m-50-250l0 300m-250-40l300 0m-40-260l0 300m-260-30l300 0m-30-270l0 300m-270-20l300 0m-20-280l0 300m-280-10l300 0m-10-290l0 300" />
  </g>
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="2%" fill="red"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="text-bottom" font-size="20" x="50" y="2" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <tspan class="tspan" x="50" dy="24">B</tspan>
    <tspan class="tspan" x="50" dy="24">BB</tspan>
    <tspan class="tspan" x="50" dy="24">BBB</tspan>
    <tspan class="tspan" x="50" dy="24">BBBB</tspan>
  </text>
   <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="2%" fill="red"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="text-bottom" font-size="20" x="150" y="64" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <tspan class="tspan" x="150" dy="24">AAAAA</tspan>
    <tspan class="tspan" x="150" dy="24">AAA</tspan>
    <tspan class="tspan" x="150" dy="24">A</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @henstrietzel Thanks,  I found if svg width is 500, then the box will be placed at 250, how can I put the box at (50,50) ? looks like middle means middle of whole width, I wish it to be middle of current text box!

Comment: @lucky1928: can you share a mockup of the desired rendering? Keep in mind: there is no text box;). A svg `<text>` elemnt rather behaves like a "line of text". All text is centered around your text element's x property value. You can also use absolute values instead of percentages. Here is a static [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/PoRPzro)  example to illustrate the concept

Comment: I have added a update section in question!

Comment: @lucky1928: I've added a second snippet. Essentially you need to use the same x for text and tspan elements since tspan x coordinates are also absolute (and not relative to the parent text element)

Comment: @heristrietzel Thanks, just check the first box 50,50, but actual location not match that position, I wish the text box center located at 50,50.

Comment: @lucky1928: pardon me my update message was omitted. The second snippet now includes some vertical adjustments based on the total number of lines. As mentioned before, you will always need to tweak these offset values, since svg text elements have no idea of it's total width or height (yeah, they are rather quirky ;)